# basic html css positioning

Tags: html, css, position

I am having some trouble with some very basic html. I am trying to center embedded video to the center of the tv screen image. the whole code is as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PLAYTHEGAME</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
 background-color: #000;
}
#test {
width: 1200px;
position: relative;
left : 50%;
top:auto;
margin-left: -600px;
z-index:2;
}
#video{
    margin-top:-925px;
    margin-left:-13px;
}
</style>

</head> 

<body>

    <div class="test"> <div align="center"> 
        <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34669221/2323232.png" border="0" />
    </div>
</body>
<div id="video"><div align="center"> <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/62981335?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=0d0d0d&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" width="740" height="420" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
```

The main problem is when you zoom in or out, the video no longer centers to the TV screen image. Please help me position the video and background image to not move when zooming or resizing the window.

Comment: Its already in center at firefox. There is no such problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your background image has a fixed size you can position #video absolutely.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwPF9/)

```
#video {
    position:absolute;
    left:577px;
    top:166px;
}
```

Note that in my fiddle I cleaned up your HTML removing the redundant elements.

```
<div class="test">
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34669221/2323232.png" border="0" />
    <div id="video">
            <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/62981335?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=0d0d0d&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" width="740" height="420" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. test is a class, so it is .test
2. prefer div video as
   position:absolute;
3. you forgot the closing tag  of class "test"

This is the whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PLAYTHEGAME</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
 background-color: #000;
}
.test {
width: 1200px;
position: relative;
left : 50%;
top:auto;
margin-left: -600px;
z-index:2;
}
#video{
position:absolute;
    top:14.5%;
    left:47.5%;
}
</style>

</head> 

<body>

    <div class="test"> <div align="center"> 
        <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34669221/2323232.png" border="0" />
    </div>
</body>
<div id="video">
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/62981335?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=0d0d0d&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" width="740" height="420" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to center your element there are many ways, one of this is below..

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="videoWrapper">
       <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34669221/2323232.png" border="0" />

  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
.videoWrapper {
  width:500px; /* set your own width */
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "center" tag to put keep your video to center

and also you can set top margin as per screen resolution by following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var height = (($(window).height()) / 2) - 50;
    $('.video').css('top', height ); 
    });
<scrript>
```